# Bot Framework Button tracking

Tags: bots, botframework

Is there any way to track HttpAction buttons within the bot framework?

I have a button to links off to a website, and need to track how often that button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle any callbacks, you can count them and store into [IBotData](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/db/d9b/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_internals_1_1_i_bot_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the actionType `OpenUrl` this is impossible. The action will be handled by the channel and there will be no message send to the bot.